# Why would the dot product yield the supplement of the Angle between two planes?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

In order to find the angle of intersection between two planes, we use the dot product of the normal vectors. However, we know there will be two possible normal vectors for each plane, making it four possible normal vectors in total (say na1, na2, and nb1, nb2). 
Let the angle between the original vectors be = α. Let also the angle between each pair of the normal vectors be = β (just to distinguish the normal vectors from the original vectors). Then, from the dot product, the angle between each pair of the different possibilities of normal vector combinations will either be α, or 180-α 
i.e. angle between:
na1, nb1 = β
na2, nb2 = β
where β = α  in these two cases

Also,
na1, nb2 = β 
na2, nb1 = β
where β = 180-α  in these two cases

I realized that in a programming scenario, the dot product will give you either α, or its supplement (180-α). Question then is at what conditions would the dot product give you the supplementary angle? How do you ensure that your calculation gives you the correct angle (α) between the original planes? Is there any mathematical means (or formulation) that can ensure you obtain α directly from your calculation, and not the supplement?

Comment: You could just take whichever value is between $0^\circ$ and $90^\circ$.

Comment: and what happens when the angle between the two original planes is more than 90 degrees?

Comment: I wouldn't say there is a "the angle".  There are *two* angles between any two intersecting planes in $\Bbb R^3$.  So you need some way to choose between the two.  One way is the choose the smaller of the two (the one between $0^\circ$ and $90^\circ$).  Another way, which works if the planes are *oriented*, is to find the angle between their *positive normals* (meaning if $\{u,v\}$ is an oriented basis for the plane, then you choose the normal $n$ such that $\{u,v,n\}$ is positively oriented with respect to your orientation on $\Bbb R^3$).

Comment: Just as [two intersecting lines form four angles](https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/vertically-opposite-angles.html), two of which are $\theta$ and two are $180^\circ - \theta$, similarly two intersecting planes form both $\theta$ and $180^\circ - \theta$. How do you know which one is the "correct" angle? They are both correct.

Comment: @Bye_world: I am dealing with 2D planes at the moment.

Comment: @Rahul: they can't be both correct. The original angle has to be θ and not 180-θ (consider that i might need the actual value for some other stuff.... possibly engineering calculation?), besides one cosine is -ve, the other is +ve. –

Comment: @User110 All planes are 2D. ;)  My comment stands.  There are two angles between any two intersecting planes (in $\Bbb R^3$).  Just pick some convention for deciding between the two and stick with it.

Comment: I see your point @Bye_world. Your obviously right. However, its easy to imagine mathematically but in trying to code it, it becomes tricky.

Comment: Use $|P \circ Q|$ instead of just $P \circ Q$.